# Why was Patches O'Houlihan in a wheelchair?

Tags: character, dodgeball

In the movie Dodgeball, Patches O'Houlihan was once a spry ADAA All-Star. But by the time Peter LaFleur and the team meet him, he's in a wheelchair.

My Question: Does the movie ever explain *why* Patches O'Houlihan is in a wheelchair? Did he suffer some sort of an injury?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never stated in the film why he needs the wheelchair other than his advanced age and infirmity. It can be inferred that years of hard living are the primary reason; but it is never explicitly stated in the film.

Comment: I don't remember seeing any references either.